# Redirect rules in web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

Can anyone help?

I have a few websites and trying to set up some redirect rules, I have the following:

- MASTERsite.com
- SiteA.com
- SiteB.com

In IIS Mastersite.com has SiteA.com and SiteB.com set on the bindings.
Currently if someone goes to SiteA.com it goes to MASTERsite.com.

However I want it to go to MASTERsite.com/FolderA/

And if someone goes to SiteA.com/Sector/ANewsArticle/ I would like it to go to:
MASTERsite.comm/Sector/ANewsArticle/

Can a redirect rule be set in the web.config file for SiteA and SiteB?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about service binding. Please follow the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733051(v=vs.110).aspx